# Angular 6 - Triggering reactive form control value changes in tests

Tags: angular

I have a subscription to a form control valueChanges observable as follows

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.search.valueChanges.pipe(
      debounceTime(300)
    ).subscribe((searchText: string) => {
      if (searchText.length > 0) {
        this.performSearch(searchText);
      } else {
        this.searchResults = [];
      }
    });
  }
```

I want to test that when changing the value to something non empty it calls my performSearch function.

I am struggling to figure out how to trigger the valueChanges, I have tried things like:

```
component.search.setValue('brad');
fixture.detectChanges();
fixture.whenStable().then(() => {
  expect(mockTmdbSearchService.multiSearch).toHaveBeenCalledWith('brad');//this is what my performSearch function calls
});
```

My spy does not get called, I suspect I have not set something up correctly to detect the form control value change in my test.

Whats the correct approach here for Forms\ReactiveForms testing in Angular?

Thanks

Comment: If is reactive can you show the init of the form? this is for an Autocomplete? more info please!